Python set does not remove duplicate NaNs
Applying set() to a list containing multiple NaN values usually removes duplicate NaN entries.
Example:
set([np.nan, 5, np.nan, 17, 5, np.nan, 23])

yields:
{5, 17, nan, 23}

However, I now have a list originating from summing (concatenating) different lists contained in a column of a dataframe; some of these lists contain NaNs. When I apply set() to the concatenated list retrieved from , it does not remove duplicate NaNs. See the below screenshot:

The object a1 from the screenshot is definitely of list type. I'm not sure, but maybe it depends on if the NaNs were at some point within a numpy array (or pandas dataframe, presumably):

set([np.nan, np.nan, np.nan]) yields {nan}
set(np.array([np.nan, np.nan])) yields {nan, nan, nan}
set(list(np.array([np.nan, np.nan]))) also yields {nan, nan, nan}

Any ways to avoid this other than np.unique() or pd.unique()? Any reason why set() would behave like this (I'd assume the expected default would be to remove duplicate NaNs, even if NaN != NaN!)?

np.nan is not equal to itself. That's why you get apparently inconsistent results from set() (hint: try proving that a is in set([a, a]) multiple times when a == a is False). If you need to get rid of nan-values, you can use .isnan().

Equality checks can be expensive so set() compares equality by checking the hash first and only if they are equal checking equality. If I run [hash(item) for item in list(np.array([np.nan, np.nan]))] I get [[8745833003041, 8745833003023], i.e. different hashes. I don't know why this is or have time to look into it right now but you could normalise your np.nan values by replacing with values with equal hashes. Though I think np.unique() seems like the appropriate tool here.

Note that NaN values also aren't unique: there are many, many different NaN values. np.nan may be a reference to one of them (and so your first example really does contain "duplicates"), but your list may contain distinct NaN values generated some other way.

I understand that NaN != NaN and that that should be the case; I however don't understand the need for more than one NaN object (or however many different IDs there are for NaN); also I don't see why set() would make such a distinction. np.unique() and pd.unique() apparently do not, so from a technical viewpoint it is certainly possible to return a single NaN, and more importantly, as written above I think that would be the expected default behavior for most people.

The reason for what you are seeing is due to a fundamental property of NaN values.  Both python (in general) and numpy / pandas in particular implement IEEE 754 semantics for floating point numbers.

The not-a-number values float('NaN') and decimal.Decimal('NaN') are
special. Any ordered comparison of a number to a not-a-number value is
false. A counter-intuitive implication is that not-a-number values are
not equal to themselves. For example, if x = float('NaN'), 3 < x, x < 3 and x == x are all false, while x != x is true. This behavior is
compliant with IEEE 754.

(Source: 6.10.1. Value comparisons)
For more background, this Q&A explains the rationale for the behavior of NaN equality in IEEE 754:

What is the rationale for all comparisons returning false for IEEE754 NaN values?

By not removing the "duplicate" NaNs, the set() function is merely being consistent with the python specification of == when allied to NaN values.
It is not clear what the best solution would be for you.  We don't have enough context.  It depends on what the NaN values mean.  Are they a representation of missing data1 or the result of an erroneous calculation?  But I would be very suspicious of any scenario where you are turning a list that might include NaN values into a set ... whether or not the "duplicate" NaN values are present in the set.
What I am saying is that the best solution for you might be to check for NaN values in the list and raise an exception!  Either way, I don't think either python or numpy / pandas offer an easy way to de-dup the NaN values in the set.
See also: https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/9358

1 - Apparently, this is a common use-case for NaN in pandas.


Any ways to avoid this other than np.unique() or pd.unique()?

numpy.nan_to_num might be useful as

NaN is replaced by zero or by the user defined value in nan keyword

in your case just provide value which will NEVER appear in your data to represent nan, e.g. if all your value are non-negative you might use -1.0 to do so
import numpy as np
arr = np.array([0.0, np.nan, 2.1, np.nan, 5.7, np.nan])
s = set(np.nan_to_num(arr, nan=-1.0))
print(s)  # {0.0, 2.1, 5.7, -1.0} where -1.0 denotes nan

